# native php xmlrpc slow to decode xmlrpc server response

Tags: php

I'm using php's native xmlrpc library to build an xmlrpc client (php 5.3.3 on redhat 5.7). Trouble is it takes the xmlrpc_decode function atleast two seconds to decode each response sent by the server, this is causes timeouts with a second application I need to respond to.

Anyone have any idea how to speed this up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try codeigniter xml rpc..

Answer (score 0):

I got similar experience, it is slow. But I have no answer for this - you are talking about xmlrpc_decode() which is PHP native instruction http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlrpc-decode.php - when XMLRPC is installed as C extension. I don't think anything faster exists, so we just have to live with this.